# Browser not resizing container with height:auto

Tags: html, css, browser, resize

Create a container div of, for example, 1280 x 768 px, remove viewport meta tag and any decent browser will automatically resize the container to make it fit perfectly in your device even if the screen res is lower than the size of the container. but why doesn't it work with height: auto? if you want the browser to calculate the height of the container depending upon the height of children elements of it, instead of hardcoding the height, how do you do it?

```
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="container"> Lorem ipsum.... Lorem ipsum </div>  
</body>

<style>

/* if you hardcode the height it'll fit the viewport*/

div#container{ width: 1700px;  height: 1500px; }

/* if you use height:auto instead it wont be resized*/

div#container{ width: 1700px;  height: auto; }

</style>
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try setting height to `100%`?

Comment: have you tried setting min-height instead of height? Because then your height will be auto by default and should still let your browser resize in the way that you want. Eg: `min-height: 1500px;`

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Neither do I. Why not simply keep the width at `auto` as well? What's the use of making it wider than the device width?